# What Permission is neccessary to show two levels of grouped documents in a SharePoint Doc Library View

Tags: permissions, libraries, sharepoint

I have following situation like in attached screenshot. As an admin with "Full Control" I can see both levels of grouped documents. As an user with "Read" Permissions I can see all documents but not grouped by the second level.

What I need to change here?
Thanks for your help
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4TKBf.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The column of the second level was a lookup. Without Read permission it's not possible to see them. After adding users to this List everything is like expected.